# shared secret for steam trading bot

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, steam

How do i get my steam account shared secret key from Steam Desktop Authenticator for steam guard code?
[**Steam Desktop Authenticator**](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator)

I'm using [Steam totp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-totp)

```
client.on("steamGuard", function(domain, callback, lastCodeWrong){

    if(lastCodeWrong) {

        console.log("Last code wrong, trying again!");

    }

    var code = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(//SHARED SECRET HERE);

    callback(code);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Node (rather than C#), `shared_secret` is in the response for `node-steam-user`'s [`enableTwoFactor`](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-user#enabletwofactorcallback) method.